# How can i get rid of wp in front of URL

Tags: urls

I am not able to reach my website when I input my original domain name, but it works whenever I input /wp in front of it.I changed the URL from Wordpress settings but it is not working.When I input my original domain name it is asking me for the wp-config-sample file while both wp-config-sample and wp-config files are present in the root directory.Same thing with the login page, the login page is something like /wp/wp-admin.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because the wordpress installation on your FTP server is in the folder called /wp, if this is the case then you can just move the entire installation one folder up. If you have FTP login credentials then you can do this via FileZilla for example.